# How to deal with non-English characters and spaces in filename in python?

Tags: python

I want to download some files from gdrive with a python script. Files contain spaces and nonEnglish characters and I want to save them exactly with the same names. I try to create a similar file with spaces and special characters, but python gives me always
`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib import request
from urllib.parse import unquote
import os
 
base_dir = os.getcwd()
print(base_dir)
url = 'https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id=1KD3dIMaJU6SY8NX38jOW3DWQYjPGN-9A&export=download'
resource = request.urlopen(request.Request(url))

content = resource.getheader('Content-Disposition')

filename = content.split('*=')[1]
filename = unquote(filename.split("''")[1])
filepath = os.path.join(base_dir, filename)

with urlopen(url) as file:
    file_content = file.read()
    
# Save to file
with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    f.write(file_content)
```

This is the full message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\ChatExport_2023-01-07\gdrive_links.py", line 26, in <module>
with open(filepath, "w") as f:

 OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Telegram Desktop\\ChatExport_2023-01-07\\DilKoçu1 (BEN KİMİM? SİSTEMİMİZ NASIL İŞLİYOR?).mp4'
```

I am using python 3.10.4 on Windows 11

Comment: I'm on local machine didn't get the error all works fine, need more details from your side

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, works fine on my machine.

Comment: Which OS; what type of file system? If you're on Windows, what's the selected code page (`chcp` output)?

Comment: Sorry, I added more details

Comment: Why are you using urlopen twice? Which one fails? Please show the full traceback

Comment: By the way, there's probably a Google drive python library for downloading files

Comment: @OneCricketeer, first one is to get filename and second one to read the content.

Comment: @tripleee `chcp` output: Aktive Codepage: 850.

Comment: does the source filename contain a literal `?` or is that just a utf decoding failure in the terminal?  Windows doesn't allow `?` and several other ASCII characters in filenames.

Comment: You can get both the header (filename) **and** content with one request. Just use `resource` variable again, not `urlopen`